# Equivalence Relation on the common restriction of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, equivalence-relations

I need to determine whether the following is an equivalence relation on $X$:

$X = \{ f|f: A \to \mathbb{R}, A \subseteq \mathbb{R}\}$ (the set of functions from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$), functions $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: B \to \mathbb{R}$ "partially agree" if and only if their restrictions on $A \cap B$ are equal:

> $f\sim g$ if and only if $f|_{A \cap B} = g|_{A \cap B}$.

I assume that showing reflexivity and symmetry are obvious. Showing transitivity is the hard part.

I have a hunch that the relation is not reflexive, but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to show that if $f|_{A\cap B} = g|_{A \cap B}$ and $g|_{B \cap C} = h|_{B \cap C}$, then $f|_{A \cap C} = h|_{A \cap C}$ (at least this is what I **think** I'm supposed to show. All these sets, as well as the whole idea of a function restriction are confusing me a little.

Comment: The easiest situation is when $A\cap B = \varnothing = B\cap C$, but $A\cap C \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: What does a function restricted to the empty set do/look like?

Comment: It's the empty function. If you identify a function with its graph, it's the function whose graph is the empty set. So, it maps no point: it does nothing. There's no graph you can look at, it looks like nothing.